# Disable storefront pages except API

Tags: symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

I need to disable all storefront pages in ORO commerce except API and public files (js, media,etc).

I've tried to use `kernel.controller` event listener and pick out frontend requests by checking firewall context:

```
$request->get('_firewall_context') === 'security.firewall.map.context.frontend'
```

And managed to filter API controllers via checking controller instance for `AbstractFOSRestController` and `ApiDoc` related.
But couldn't find proper way to separate storefront pages and public files requests.

Answer (score 1):

1. **JS and Media** should be served directly by the webserver (usually Nginx). In this case, there is nothing to do with the application. But there is already a firewall named `assets` that have `security: false` option, so security checks are disabled there, even if these files are served by the application.
2. There are also **private attachments**. You can create one more firewall, that will be loaded before `frontend` to serve private storefront attachments separately if needed.
3. The only firewall you need to interrupt is `frontend`. You can disable access to it completely with the [firewall configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/security.html) and add [custom access denied handler](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/access_denied_handler.html) to return 404 instead of 403.

To get the full list of firewalls, you can run:

```
php bin/console debug:config security firewalls
```

**In general, it's much easier to rely on firewall names instead of the firewall context.**

Comment: some media served by controllers like Oro\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Controller\Controller, which create missing files. So it's tricky to allow them to work and disable others.

Comment: You can pre-generate them during the deployment. Then there is no need to call a controller as well.